# Word 2010 - How to make it a single page in the middle of my screen - Zooms

Tags: microsoft-word

So this is a constant issue and I somehow got it fixed, but then I just reformatted and the issue is back.

Word keeps putting pages side by side and if I click on the "One page," it shrinks the zoom down to 79% from 100%. If I go back to 100%, it goes back to 2 pages.

I'm already in print layout & the navigation pane is open.

We found a workaround where you click on web layout & then back to print layout, but then the next time I open a doc, it's back to 2 pages again.

I hope someone knows the answer and can we agree this is a bug?

Thanks

Comment: In the View pane, group Zoom, have you set "One Page"?

Comment: The utility from Word MVP Jay Freedman SaveViewMultiLoc on his Macro Zone page https://jay-freedman.info/ would likely solve this. (or one of the lesser utilities dealing with zoom). It should not be necessary but likely will help.

Comment: @harrymc - yes, sorry we did & we edited the text from single to one page.

Comment: @jay - ok, but that only works if the settings are already there, right?

And it will only save in one document, right?

Thanks

Comment: Ok, so one of the files I opened, opened in 2 pages, then switched to one page at 100%. We can't figure out why.

It seems to have this grey pane on the right, but we can't figure out how to get it on the other docs.

https://i.imgur.com/l9HNj9Z.png

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I never had such a problem. You could try to repair Office in *Control Panel > Programs and Features*.

Comment: @harry - there's nothing to repair.

I had the same issue with Word & I just reformatted & did a fresh Word install & same issues.

What version of Office are you using?

Comment: Currently Word 365, but I've used Word 2010 in the past. Questions: (1) Are your documents very high, or have anything special? (2) Is Your screen very small? What is its effective resolution? (3) Is Word displayed full-screen? And what happens if it's not?

Comment: @harry - There's nothing special about my docs. Even when creating a new doc it doesn't center it.

My screen is normal, my resolution is 1920x1080 & my screen is maximized.

If it gets smaller then yes, it will go single page. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on the comments above, we finally figured out how to solve this frustrating problem.

Once you do Ctrl F so the "find" pane is open on the left, then just mouse over the vertical right side of the pane until you get the resize handle and expand/pull it a bit towards the right, this will move the page you are seeing from left-justified to the center of your window.

Answer (score 0):

Word will go double-page if there is enough screen-space to put two pages
side-by-side.

The solution is to reduce the window-size of Word, so it cannot fit two
whole pages inside.